# How to display list of image from chosen directory in JSplitPane Java?

Tags: java, jsplitpane

Example: C:/My Documents/myFile/  taken from JChooser have a list of image.
How to display it in JSplitPane?

This is Image My file:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class FileBrowser extends JPanel implements TreeSelectionListener {    
    private JButton button;
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode top;
    private JTree tree;
    private DefaultTreeModel model;
    private JScrollPane treeView;
    private JPanel picPane;
    private JScrollPane pictureScrollPane;
    private JPanel panel;

    public FileBrowser() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        tree = new JTree();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("File Browser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        treeView = new JScrollPane(tree);
        picPane = new JPanel();
        picPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(picPane);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        picPane.add(label);
        //Add the scroll panes to a split pane.
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
        splitPane.setTopComponent(treeView);
        splitPane.setBottomComponent(pictureScrollPane);

        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 50);
        pictureScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
        treeView.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(200);
        splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 500));

        panel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("Choose File");
        BoxLayout box = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(box);

        panel.add(splitPane);
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

                int returnVal = chooser.showDialog(chooser, "Select");
                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

                    if (selectedFile.isDirectory()) {
                        top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("");
                        model = new DefaultTreeModel(top);
                        createNode(selectedFile.getPath(), top, model);

                        picPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

                        for (File f : selectedFile.listFiles()) {

                            try {
                                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(f);
                                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
                                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                                label.setIcon(icon);
                                pictureScrollPane.add(label);

                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                Logger.getLogger(FileBrowser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                            }

                            System.out.println("You chose to open this file: "
                                    + chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);    
    }

    private void createNode(String folder, DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode, DefaultTreeModel model) {
        File f = new File(folder);
        for (File aFile : f.listFiles()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(aFile.getName());
            currentNode.add(node);
            if (aFile.isFile()) {
                //do something
            } else if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
                //do something
                createNode(aFile.getPath(), node, model);
            }
        }
        tree.setModel(model);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FileBrowser();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }    
}
```

I'm new to Swing.It's too difficult to me.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What is the question ? How to display an image in a JPanel ?  How to set image position ?   What ever it is I would suggest post an [MCVE] with a narrower well focus question.

Comment: See the picture below.I want display list of image in directory where i chose at JSplitPane

Comment: I read and so the picture. " What ever it is I would suggest post an [MCVE] with a narrower well focus question" , not a "make my code work" broad question.